# Is any way to aggregate mongodb avg for meteorJS?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new bee for MeteorJS, I want to aggregate average one field from mongoldb collection. I can able to do from command line but not from code.

`db.tasks.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"",avgnum: {$avg: "$num"}}}])`

I want to get avgnum value should display on code. Please help us on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a package for aggregation support](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/), but the Meteor mongo implementation (miniMongo) doesn't support aggregations.